# Extremely Simple Linear Search Doesn't Work on Android & iOS

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I am a total beginner on C# and even more on Unity. I have tried to look for many things on here but didn't find one that solved the problem. This seems like a super simple linear search but it didn't work on iOS & Android.

It works only on my Mac when I clicked the Play button thingy on top. I have no clue at all. Just FYI, the array length is 119.

I have a JSON, the structure is as follows:

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "name": "Hydrogen",
            "symbol": "H",
            "boil": 231
        },
        {
            "name": "Sasdsad",
            "symbol": "S",
            "boil": 213
        }
    ]
}
```

and I have parsed it using a C# class,

```
public class ChemElements {

public string name;
public float boil;
public string symbol;


}
```

and then on start() method I put it inside an array called x :

```
ChemElements[] x = null;

void start(){
path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/periodic.json";
jsonstring = File.ReadAllText(path);
x = JsonHelper.FromJson<ChemElements>(jsonstring);
}
```

JsonHelper is as follows, it's just a helper class to deserialize JSON array:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(json);
        return wrapper.Items;
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper);
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array, bool prettyPrint)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper, prettyPrint);
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] Items;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to search thru the array x of ChemElements[]
by linear search (a very simple one) by matching a TextMeshPro text with the symbol property of x (array). If the symbol is found, I want to set a new value the alpha of ElPreview

```
public void eleClicked(){
        var eleBtn = GameObject.Find(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name);
        for(int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++){
            if(x[i].symbol == eleBtn.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>().text){
                    ElPreview.canvasRenderer.SetAlpha(1f);
            }
        }



    }
```

eleClicked() is an onclick function.

In the unity, as I told previously, it runs as expected. It changes the alpha value to 1, causing it to show (previously was 0).

Whereas on iOS & Android it didn't. The alpha value I assume is still 0, since it's stil transparent.

I have tried to remove the linear search, and only change the alpha value and it works on iOS & Android, therefore I know the problem lies within the linear search code.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try `.equals` instead of `==`

Comment: @Draco18s this previously worked, I swear! I tried it again and it didn't work. No script change at all. :/

Comment: The loop didn't work at all on mobile. It didn't execute the code inside it. Any code. It works only on Unity.

Comment: Are you sure you have any buttons at all on mobile?

Comment: @Draco18s It was solved earlier. The problem was caused by File.ReadAllText() . This doesn't work on mobile.

Comment: Does that mean that the issue is solved, or that it doesn't work on mobile? The wording is confusing here.

Comment: @Eliasar my bad, I was half asleep writing that. It's solved:) thanks.